# Text disappears from Hero webpart on external monitor

Tags: chrome, communication-site

When viewing a SharePoint site in Google Chrome, the "title" text of a content block in the Hero webpart gets erased if I drag the Chrome window from the internal laptop display to an external monitor. The DIV element actually loses the content.

To be clear about the steps:

1. Load SharePoint site in Chrome on laptop's internal display (text renders properly)

2. Drag Chrome window to external monitor

3. PROBLEM: Text immediately disappears (confirmed by doing an "Inspect" of the element; the DIV for the "HeroTitle" is empty)

4. Reload the page, text is still missing

5. Drag Chrome window back to internal monitor and reload page

6. Text renders correctly

I have Internet Explorer, FireFox, and Microsoft Edge all installed on this PC, and only Chrome exhibits this behavior.

Comment: More information about this issue... it seems to be a matter of the size of the page. When the Chrome window is at 1455px wide (or smaller), I can refresh the page and get the text to show up again. At 1456px or wider, the text disappears.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have the same problem on Safari (but not Chrome) when I zoom out too far and all the text disappears. When I zoom in again it'll come back